# I am unable to retrieve column value in a Telerik radgrid.

Tags: mysql, telerik, radgrid, data-retrieval

I am trying to select a column value in a selected row but I am unable to select the row. It seems that after clicking on the row to be selected, it does not go into the if statement. If I change the if statement to (dataItem.Selected = true) with only one "=", it goes in but returns the invoice id for all of the rows. Any advice on how to resolve this issue?

```
protected void RadGrid1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var a ="";
        foreach (GridDataItem dataItem in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items)
        {
            if (dataItem.Selected == true)
            {

                a = dataItem.GetDataKeyValue("InvoiceId").ToString();
                Response.Write(a);
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you allow multiple selections or only just single selection in your RadGrid?

To me, the foreach loop code block doesn't seem correct if you do single row selection.

```
protected void RadGrid1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // get selected row
   GridDataItem item =(GridDataItem)RadGrid1.SelectedItems[0]; 
}
```

Also, another point is you should set `EnablePostBackOnRowClick` property to true so that RadGrid's `SelectedIndexChanged` event will be fired properly on the server side.

```
<ClientSettings Selecting-AllowRowSelect="true" EnablePostBackOnRowClick="true">
</ClientSettings>
```

But if you wish to fire row select command from client side, then you should add a row click event with JS.

```
function RowClick(sender, eventArgs) {
    sender.get_masterTableView().fireCommand("Select", eventArgs.get_itemIndexHierarchical());
}
```

Then associate that JS function to `<ClientEvents OnRowClick="RowClick" />` in your aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RadGrid1.SelectedItems[0] To get your selected item.

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
     var myDataItem = RadGrid1.SelectedItems[0] as GridDataItem;   
     if (myDataItem != null)   
     {   
         var name = myDataItem ["InvoiceId"].Text;   
     }   
}
```

And Woodykiddy is right. Check your postback and your allow row selecting.
And if you re using ajax dont forget the rad Ajax manager and panel.